# Angular can't access components after ng build

Tags: angular, iis

my angular app works ok in ng serve. But after ng build and put in IIS, only the index page is accessible but all others are not accessible. Not quite sure the issue, any suggestion?

Error
[image]

IIS setting
[image]

angular.json

```
 {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "CrisprDataPortal": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/CrisprDataPortal",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "200kb",
                  "maximumError": "200kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "CrisprDataPortal:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "CrisprDataPortal:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "CrisprDataPortal:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "CrisprDataPortal"
}
```

Comment: This is IIS issue, not Angular.

Comment: @BojanKogoj Thanks. I added the IIS setting in the post. Not quite sure if I missed anything

Comment: Are you using routing? Is your IIS configured for URL rewriting? See the documentation here for more information: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: Can you share which files you put on IIS? You did `ng build` and copied only the content of `dist` folder?

Comment: I'm not familiar with IIS, but did you redirect all subpages to index.html? You should let Angular router deal with it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you didnot configure url rewrite, then IIS try to find project folder under root folder, not route it to angular.

Try to add this in web.config. You can change the rewritten url according to your need.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
  <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```